# Irreducible polynomials of degree 2 over $\mathbb{F}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am trying to figure out a quick way to determine the 2nd degree polynomials of $\mathbb{F}_4$ that are irreducible. I already know that for degree 1, we have $x$, $x+1$, $x+a$, $x+b$. From here it is clear that the following 2nd degrees are reducible:

$x*x=x^2$

$x(x+1)=x^2+x$

$x(x+a)=x^2+ax$

$x(x+b)=x^2+bx$

$(x+1)(x+1)=x^2+ax+1$

$(x+1)(x+a)=x^2+bx+a$

$(x+1)(x+b)=x^2+(1+b)x+b=x^2+(1+a+1)x+b=x^2+ax+b$

$(x+a)(x+a)=x^2+(a+a)x+b=x^2+b$

$(x+a)(x+b)=x^2+(a+b)x+a(1+a)=x^2+(a+1+a)x+(a+b)=x^2+x+1$

$(x+b)(x+b)=x^2+(b+b)x+(a+1)b=x^2+ab+b=x^2+a(a+1)+b=x^2+b+a+b=x^2+a$

So the remaining 2nd degree polynomials are:

$x^2+1$, $x^2+ax+a$, $x^2+bx+b$, $x^2+x+a$, $x^2+x+b$, $x^2+bx+1$

Am I on the right track here? How would I test the remaining ones to see if they are irreducible?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what $2,3 \in \mathbb F_4$ are? I suspect you're mixing up $\mathbb F_4 \neq \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$!

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{F}_4$ has ${0,1,w,\bar{w}}$, so if you just let $w=2$ and $\bar{w}=3$, it is all the same, isn't it?

Comment: @user3784030 And then what would $\;2\cdot3\;$ in your notation be? Not to mention that using the symbol $"2"$ in a field of characteristic $\;2\;$ seems to be an invitation to confusion.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. In my notation $2*3=6=2 mod 4$, when in normal notation $w*\bar{w}=1$. My bad, I will have to fix this up.

Comment: Then you know $3+3=0$ and $2+2=0$? Check here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field

Comment: In any ring, numbers like $2$ or $7$ naturally make sense in a canonical way : they are $1+1+\dots +1$ ; so you can't just assign them to any element because it seems to make sense in the context. You can also state this by saying that there is a unique ring morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to any ring.

Answer (score 1):

In any field, a polynomial of degree $2$ is reducible if and only if it is split. So your method of listing all possible split polynomials does give all the reducible ones (and then by taking the complement, the irreducible ones).

On the other hand, you need to fix your notation for the elements of $\mathbb{F}_4$ as pointed out in the comments, it gives false results (even though the method itself is valid).

Comment: I have edited my question, correcting the notation: after doing so, I was able to find that there are 16 in total (which makes sense, as $4^2$ combinations), and I found 5 that did not appear to be reducible: $x^2+1$, $x^2+ax+a$, $x^2+bx+b$, $x^2+x+a$, $x^2+x+b$, $x^2+bx+1$. Is this correct?

Comment: You corrected the notation, but not the calculations. You still write that $a=1+1$ when you write $(x+1)(x+1)=x^2 + ax +1$. The problem is not so much the notation itself as the fact that it gives wrong answers : in $\mathbb{F_4}$, $1+1=2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Any quadratic $\Bbb F_4$-irreducible polynomial has its roots in $\Bbb F_{16}$, say $\rho$ and $\bar\rho$, forming an $\Bbb F_4$-conjugate pair of elements of $\Bbb F_{16}$. And each such pair gives you a unique monic quadratic polynomial irreducible over $\Bbb F_4$.

There are sixteen elements of $\Bbb F_{16}$, and four of them are in $\Bbb F_4$ — each of those is its own conjugate. Since there are twelve elements of $\Bbb F_{16}\setminus\Bbb F_4$, these fall into six conjugate pairs. So there are just six monic irreducible quadratics over $\Bbb F_4$.

Comment: Do the solutions I listed up there look correct? I tried to test them, and they seem to be good, but I am not sure.

Comment: No, $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$, and I think you’re missing $x^2+ax+1$. I suspect that the others are right. It’s easy enough to check, by just substituting in the four elements of $\Bbb F_4$ and verifying that the result is never zero.